# How do I stop a function from being called until there is a touch on the screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I have an object on screen as soon as the app launches. I have a method that randomly starts placing more of that same object when the app launches, but I want that to happen after the app registers a touch.
How can I do that? I think it would have to be something in my touches began method, but I can't seem to get my code working.

This is what I did after Jacob's post:

```
func viewdidload() {

    self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "viewTapped:"))

}

func viewTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

   func spawnObject() 
   self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "viewTapped:")) 

}
```

I think I'm missing something out of this.

Here is my touches began method:
     override func touchesBegan(touches: Set, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

```
        if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {

        if self.touch == false {

            self.touch = true
            self.spawnObjects()

        }

        }

        if !ball.physicsBody!.dynamic {

        startGameTextNode.removeFromParent()
        ball.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    }

    if (moving.speed > 0) {
        ball.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
        ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 8))
    } else if (canRestart) {
        self.resetScene()
    }
}
```

Comment: post some code and please point where exactly you are having problem. What works and what doesn't. This will help you get an answer quickly.

Comment: Does the view has any "touchable" object?, I mean, what If you add a gesture recognizer to the whole view, that works for you?, If so I can write down how you can do it.

Comment: I'm fairly new to iOS development and I couldn't even understand where to start. I do have a touches began method, which applies an impulse to the object and thats it, but I can't understand how to go about it.

Comment: To clarify, after the user touches anywhere on the screen, you want to app to start randomly placing new objects (random times, random position)?

Comment: Yes, for which I have the spawnObject method.

Answer (score 2):

In your viewDidLoad() method add the following code:

```
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(self, "viewTapped:"))
```

Then implement the following method:

```
func viewTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

CALL YOUR METHOD HERE
self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(self, "viewTapped:"))
}
```

This now means that as soon as a tap is registered anywhere on the screen, your method will be called.

Comment: Still couldn't get it working. Sorry for not getting it. I'm fairly new to iOS Development, but I wrote my code to show what i did. Do I add the whole spawn method in fun viewTapped?

Comment: No problem! I've only been doing iOS dev for about 6 months myself. If you call your spawn method in the viewTapped method like: mySpawnMethod()

Answer (score 0):

if you want the function to be called only for once...then declare a bool

```
var touched = false

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
          if self.touched == false {
          self.touched = true
          spawnObject() 

}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for responding. yes, I only want the function to be called once which is when the game starts upon touching. I did what you just said, but it gave an error on func spawnObject() line, saying "Expected '(' in body of function declaration". I do have other things too in my touches began method, like, implying impulse on every touch. I don't know if that is interfering.

Comment: you need to call the method in the if loop...i have edited it now.

Comment: I think I'm confusing stuff up. Please forgive me, I'm fairly new to iOS development. I have posted my touches began method so that you can look at it.

Comment: What are you doing with your func spawnobject() line?? it makes no sense.You can just call a func in your touchesbegan method.

Comment: what is the code (method) you want to run with the touch event?

Comment: As a learner, I'm trying to rebuild flappy bird game to understand some of the concepts. I have pasted the spawnObject() method. The game perfectly launches and starts when the app launches. All I'm trying to accomplish is stopping spawnObject method being called till a player touches on the screen. When game launches, pipes start to spawn, but I want them to start spawning once the game launches and a user has touches the screen once.

Comment: yeah i got it sharukh...but when your are calling the function,it shouldnt be func spawnobject()...make it self.spawnobject() or just spawnobject() :)

Comment: That is the only thing you are missing...Hope you got it:)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. Putting self.spawnObject() didn't work. Pipes started to spawn without a touch.

Comment: hmmm...can you edit your post and paste the exact code again ?

Comment: Hey, I figured it out. Me just being dumb and not realizing what actions I had created before. I had created an SKAction that spawned pipes in a sequence of 2s intervals, which included the spawnobject function and I just moved it in touches began method, instead of self.spawnobjects(). I really appreciate for helping me out. Would have taken me ages to figure it out :)